# Avoid printing static text in label_format string of Wagtail's StructBlock given a certain condition

Tags: wagtail

Let's suppose I have a `StructBlock` named *PersonBlock*. It has this structure:

```py
class PersonBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    first_name = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    last_name = blocks.CharBlock()

    class Meta:
        label_format = '{last_name}, {first_name}'
        icon = 'user'
```

and I use it like:

```py
body = StreamField([
    ('person', PersonBlock()),
], use_json_field=True)
```

When the `StructBlock` is collapsed, and *first_name* is empty, the string is displayed as `Random,`  (where *last_name* = "Random"), or when the data has not yet been saved is rendered as `,`  (only the comma and the space are displayed, since it doesn't render the empty fields, which is correct.). In this case, how do I print only *last_name* (without the comma and space) if *first_name* is empty? (I don't wanna use a default value!)

I know that I can't use this:

```py
class Meta:
    label_format = first_name # just trying in this example with this field, without "last_name"
```

or this:

```py
class Meta:
    label = '{}'.format(first_name) # just trying in this example with this field, without "last_name"
    label_format = label
```

because it returns the error below:

> NameError: name 'first_name' is not defined

---

The only reference for `label_format` that I found in [docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#wagtail.blocks.StructBlock) is (emphasis mine):

> label_format – Determines the label shown when the block is collapsed in the editing interface. By default, the value of the first sub-block in the StructBlock is shown, but this can be customised by setting a string here with block names contained in braces - for example **label_format = "Profile for {first_name} {surname}"**

---

So: how do I avoid printing static text given a certain condition (in this case that one of the field values is None)?

I'm using Wagtail 5.2.